# How do we connect raspberry pi 3 to wifi after reboot?

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-3

I have connected my pi 3 to wifi network but I want it to be connected again to the same network even when it is turned off and then turned on again. How can we do it?

Comment: Are you using Raspbian? How did you connect to the wifi network initially (e.g. manually inserting credentials into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, into '/etc/network/interfaces` or using the Pixel GUI)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an up to date Raspbian:

Your wifi credentials (network name aka SSID, password) are saved in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. If wifi is enabled (which it is by default), it should automatically reconnect after a reboot using those.